# Mysql | Join data from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql

I've been studying and researching for a while about how to perform such a 'join' between 2 tables, but, so far, without any success.

The case is as follows:

I have 2 tables with 1 column in common between them. What I need is to literally join the whole table using that mentioned column. Below is an example:

Table 1:

| Nome | Idade |
| --- | --- |
| Nome_1 | Idade_1 |

Table 2:

| Nome | Endereço | Sexo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nome_1 | Endereço_1 | Sexo_1 |

Output:

| Nome | Endereço | Sexo | Idade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nome_1 | Endereço_1 | Sexo_1 | Idade_1 |

Comment: Please translate to english and add what you have so far there are examples of 2 table joins in the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table2 JOIN table1 USING (Nome)`